# validate a cell based on another cell value in datagrid in silverlight

Tags: xaml, data-binding, datagrid, silverlight-4.0, validation

PFB the code for datagrid in our silverlight app,i need to validate the column AttributeValue in each row based on other column value DatatypeName, for example the DatatypeNamecolumn value for a particular row is int the  AttributeValue column in the same row should allow user only int ,if user enters other than int the cell should throw  validation exception.Please help

```
<sdk:DataGrid Margin="0,0,0,50" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" RowStyle="{StaticResource DataGridRowStyle1}"  Style="{StaticResource DataGridStyle1}" IsReadOnly="True" Foreground="{StaticResource GrayBrush}" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Name="dgKpiAttributes" MinHeight="5" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" FontSize="13.333" FontFamily="Segoe UI"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLinesVisibility="None" >
                                                    <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                                                        <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header=" " >
                                                            <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                                                <DataTemplate>
                                                                    <CheckBox x:Name="chkSelect" 
                                      VerticalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="False"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>


                                                                </DataTemplate>
                                                            </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                                        </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                                                        <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="AttributeName" SortMemberPath="AttributeName" Width="50*" >
                                                            <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                                                <DataTemplate>
                                                                    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                                                        <TextBlock x:Name="txtAttributeName" TextWrapping="Wrap" Padding="4" Text="{Binding AttributeName}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                                                    </StackPanel>
                                                                </DataTemplate>
                                                            </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                                        </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                                                        <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="AttributeValue" SortMemberPath="AttributeValue" Width="80*" >
                                                            <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                                                <DataTemplate>
                                                                    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                                                        <TextBox x:Name="AttributeValue"  Margin="0,0,10,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Text="{Binding AttributeValue}"  TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                                                                    </StackPanel>
                                                                </DataTemplate>
                                                            </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                                        </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                                                        <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="DataType" SortMemberPath="DataTypeName" Width="50*">
                                                            <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                                                <DataTemplate>
                                                                    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">

                                                                        <TextBox x:Name="DatatypeName"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  TextWrapping="Wrap" IsEnabled="False"  Text="{Binding DataTypeName}" />
                                                                    </StackPanel>
                                                                </DataTemplate>
                                                            </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                                        </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                                                    </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>

                                                </sdk:DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, from your code I can see your class is like this (correct me if I'm mistaken):

```
class MyClass
{
      public string AttributeName {get;set;}
      public string AttributeValue {get;set;}
      public string DatatypeName {get;set;}
}
```

In silverligth, I suppose there is a way to check another cells in the same row in a datagrid, but since you are working with bindings, you do not need that, you can work directly in your data object:

```
class MyClass
{
      public string AttributeName {get;set;}

      public string DatatypeName {get;set;}

      private string _AttributeValue;
      public string AttributeValue {
             get{
                  return _AttributeValue;  
             }
             set{
                  if (validate(DatatypeName,value)){
                    //Do something if validation is a success  
                    _AttributeValue = value;
                  }
                  else{
                     //Do something if validation fails
                  }
              }
          }

      bool validate(string typename,string value){
        //do your validation, return true or false
        return true
      }


}
```

This way you do not need to concern yourself with traversing the UI, only with the data.